# haskell - LYAH - Making our own Types and our Type Classes

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

The haskell code below compiles, Ok.

```
data Point = Point Float Float  
data Radius = Radius Float  
data Shape = Circle Point Radius
```

Is it possible to write something in line with the code below (Code fails compiling):

```
data LengthQty = Radius Float | Length Float | Width Float   
data Shape = Circle Point Radius
```

Idea behind this attempt is that Radius, Length and Width are representing Physical Quantity Length.

Please note that in the second part second line if written like

```
data Shape = Circle Point LengthQty
```

Then, it compiles, but in that case the "LengthQty" can be anything like Length, Width or Radius, where only Radius is required.

(1) What is wrong in second part?
(2) How it can be corrected to implement the idea of Physical Quantity Length (LengthQty)?

Comment: That's IMO not one of the best examples in LYAH, `data Radius = Radius Float` is actually a rather stupid definition, you'd normally just write `type Radius = Float` for this kind of stuff. And use record systax to further clarify the meaning of each field in `Circle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your code doesn't compile is that the right-hand side of a data declaration must be a *constructor* followed by a list of *types*, i.e. of the form

```
data {-type-} = {-constructor-} {-type-} ... {-type-}
```

In your example, when you define

```
data LengthQty = Radius Float | Length Float | Width Float
```

you have made `LengthQty` a *type* whereas `Radius`, `Length` and `Width` are *constructors*. Therefore when you write

```
data Shape = Circle Point Radius
```

the compiler sees something of the form

```
data {-type-} = {-constructor-} {-type-} {-constructor-}
```

i.e. it sees a constructor where it is expecting a type, so it throws an error. In the original code, the symbol `Radius` was used for both a constructor and a type. When the compiler sees

```
data Shape = Circle Point Radius
```

it knows that `Radius` in this context has to be a type, so there is no possibility of confusion with the *constructor* radius.

With this in mind, you can make your code compile correctly if you just write

```
data Shape = Circle Point LengthQty
```

and you can get a particular instance of a circle with

```
circle :: Shape
circle = Circle (Point 0 0) (Radius 1)
```

Comment: Is there any possibility where Type Classes can has Sub Type Classes in haskell?

Comment: Typeclasses can have subclasses, but the word 'subclass' means something different than what it does in OO languages.

Comment: @Optimight Not really. You can do a context requirement for an instance, though... However, the context requirement is checked after and isn't used in the resolving process.

Comment: @alternative Can you please explain with the given example? I am an absolute beginner and not able to interpret your comment in actual code.

Answer (score 2):

This compiles:

```
data Point = Point Float Float  
data Radius = Radius Float  
data Shape = Circle Point Radius

data LengthQty = R Float | Length Float | Width Float
```

`Radius` is name of the type and also of data constructor of type `Float -> Radius`; `R` is a data constructor of type `Float -> LengthQty`. You can't have two different data constructors with same name. The **name** `Radius` is **already taken**.

The following also works:

```
data LengthQty = R Radius | Length Float | Width Float
```

Without `R`, `Radius` by itself would be a data constructor of type `:: LengthQty`, which would, again, clash with `Radius :: Float -> Radius`.

Comment: Is there any possibility where Type Classes can have Sub Type Classes in haskell?

Comment: You aren't using any classes here. You are using data types. But classes in Haskell (which are completely different from object-oriented classes) can indeed have subclasses.

Comment: dflemstr: Yes, I read it but completely missed it while putting up my question in comment. Still the  Object Oriented Paradigm thinking overrides. My question should have been: " Is there any possibility where data-types can have sub-data-types in haskell?

Comment: @Optimight: in OO terms, haskell datatypes support 'has-a" relationships, but not 'is-a'.  Type classes provide support for polymorphic functions, but trying to use them like OO classes is generally unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

The useful difference between

```
data Point = Point Float Float  
data Radius = Radius Float  
data Shape = Circle Point Radius
```

and
`data LengthQty = Radius Float | Length Float | Width Float`

is the way Haskell's type system handles them. Haskell has a powerful type system, which makes sure that a function is passed data that it can handle. The reason you'd write a definition like `LengthQuantity` is if you had a function which could take either a `Radius`, `Length`, or `Width`, which your function can't do.

If you *did* have a function which could take a `Radius`, `Length`, or `Width`, I'd write your types like this:

```
data Point = Point Float Float  
data Radius = Radius Float  
data Shape = Circle Point Radius

data LengthQty = R Radius
               | L Length 
               | W Width
```

This way, functions that can only take a `Radius` benefit from that more specific type checking.